# Event attendee ID missing on Google Calendar Events list response

Tags: google-calendar-api

The Google Calendar specifies that it will return an array of [`Event`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) resources that will also include:

> `attendees[].id` (`string`) The attendee's Profile ID, if available. It
>   corresponds to theid field in the People collection of the Google+ API

However, when I invoke the [`Events:list`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) API it returns me an attendee with the following properties only:

```
{
  "email": "attendee.address@gmail.com",
  "displayName": "Attendee Name",
  "responseStatus": "accepted"    
}
```

I would like to fetch more information (and namely the user avatar) for this user/attendee by invoking the [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people), however, without an `ID` I can't do much.

The endpoint that I am using to fetch events is `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarId}/events?${params}` which I confirm is the latest API version.

Any thoughts on this issue would be much welcome!

Comment: Did you set the `maxAttendees` parameter in your request? I think you need this to get the attendees.

Comment: `maxAttendees` is a property to set `The maximum number of attendees to include in the response`. By default the value is `1+` meaning no restriction.  So it is not quite relevant to the question at hand. I am currently getting a list of attendees... it just doesn't include an `ID` property which I can use to fetch the attendee's avatar

Comment: It is stated in the documentation that they will return attendees id, if available. There is a chance that there isn't any id set for the particular id in the first place.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue, did you found any solution?

Comment: Hi, please was anybody succesfull in getting user_id from email or from Calendar Event API? I am looking for the same use case.